# How could I speed up this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have this query:

```
select 
    a.*, 
    trunc(MAX(rebase.circulating_supply) * a.supply_percentage, 9) as ampl_balance, 
    trunc(
        MAX(rebase.circulating_supply) *
        (coalesce(SUM(t.supply_percentage) FILTER (WHERE t.to = a.contract_address), 0) +
        (coalesce(SUM(t.supply_percentage) FILTER (WHERE t.from = a.contract_address), 0) * -1)),
        9
    ) as net_ampl_moved
from addresses as a
cross join (select r.circulating_supply from rebases r order by r.timestamp desc limit 1) as rebase
left join transfers as t
on (t.from = a.contract_address or t.to = a.contract_address) and t.timestamp >= ?
group by a.contract_address;
```

The goal here is to aggregate the net balance of an account over a certain time period e.g. from last 24 hours, all time etc. I do this by summing every transaction out and every transaction in.

Indexes on transfers:

```
 CREATE INDEX transfers_from_to_index ON public.transfers USING btree ("from", "to")
 CREATE INDEX transfers_timestamp_index ON public.transfers USING btree ("timestamp")
 CREATE INDEX transfers_action_index ON public.transfers USING btree (action)
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX transfers_pkey ON public.transfers USING btree (transaction_hash, log_index)
 CREATE INDEX transfers_supply_percentage_index ON public.transfers USING btree (supply_percentage)
 CREATE INDEX transfers_amount_index ON public.transfers USING btree (amount)
 CREATE INDEX transfers_supply_percentage_timestamp_log_index_index ON public.transfers USING btree (supply_percentage, "timestamp", log_index)
 CREATE INDEX transfers_from_index ON public.transfers USING btree ("from")
 CREATE INDEX transfers_to_index ON public.transfers USING btree ("to")
```

Indexes on addresses:

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX addresses_pkey ON public.addresses USING btree (contract_address)
 CREATE INDEX addresses_supply_percentage_index ON public.addresses USING btree (supply_percentage)
```

Indexes on rebase:

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX rebases_pkey ON public.rebases USING btree (epoch)
 CREATE INDEX rebases_timestamp_index ON public.rebases USING btree ("timestamp")
```

Explain plan:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/1Zy

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check the stat tab in the explain, ~92% over an index scan

Comment: How would you go about optimising it? I am a beginner at query optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left join on `transfers` is the most costly part, largely due to the `OR` and there being no good index to solve it.

Mybe try this?

```
select 
    a.*, 
    trunc(
        MAX(rebase.circulating_supply)
          * a.supply_percentage,
        9
    ) as ampl_balance, 
    trunc(
        MAX(rebase.circulating_supply)
          * coalesce(SUM(t.supply_percentage), 0),
        9
    ) as net_ampl_moved
from addresses as a
cross join (select r.circulating_supply from rebases r order by r.timestamp desc limit 1) as rebase
left join (
  select tt.to   as contract_address, tt.timestamp,  tt.supply_percentage from transfers tt
  union all
  select tf.from as contract_address, tf.timestamp, -tf.supply_percentage from transfers tf
) t
on t.contract_address = a.contract_address and t.timestamp >= ?
group by a.contract_address;
```

Then have two new indexes in `transfers`...

```
CREATE INDEX transfers_to_timestamp_index
  ON public.transfers
  USING btree ("to", "timestamp")
  INCLUDE ("supply_percentage");

CREATE INDEX transfers_from_timestamp_index
  ON public.transfers
  USING btree ("from", "timestamp")
  INCLUDE ("supply_percentage");
```

That should make both the join and the aggregate cheaper.

***EDIT:*** An alternative...

Using the same indexes as mentioned above, but collapsing all the aggregation to a sub query on just the transfers table.

*(And moving the sub-queries to CTEs for readability...)*

```
WITH
  t_normalised
AS
(
  select tt.to   as contract_address, tt.timestamp,  tt.supply_percentage from transfers tt
  union all
  select tf.from as contract_address, tf.timestamp, -tf.supply_percentage from transfers tf
),
  t_sum
AS
(
  SELECT
    contract_address,
    SUM(supply_percentage)  AS supply_percentage
  FROM
    t_normalised
  WHERE
    timestamp >= ?
  GROUP BY
    contract_address
),
  rebase
AS
(
  select r.circulating_supply
    from rebases r
order by r.timestamp desc
   limit 1
) 
select 
    a.*, 
    trunc(
        rebase.circulating_supply
          * a.supply_percentage,
        9
    ) as ampl_balance, 
    trunc(
        rebase.circulating_supply
          * coalesce(t_sum.supply_percentage, 0),
        9
    ) as net_ampl_moved
from
  addresses as a
cross join
  rebase
left join
  t_sum
    on t_sum.contract_address = a.contract_address
```

Comment: @OultimoCoder I'd love to see the execution plans for these, if you're able to create the two new indexes.

Comment: Of course! I have just been testing them (indexes are created), here is your first query and your second query's explain plans all with the same timestamp aka one year in the past: first: https://explain.depesz.com/s/ZGn0 second: https://explain.depesz.com/s/pccD

Comment: I have both indexes created exactly as you listed, the first query is a bit slow but the second one is a lot faster than my original query! And thanks so much for helping me!

Comment: I just noticed that these two plans are for a year, and the OP was for just part of a day.  It makes much more sense now :)

Comment: I actually upped my database from 1 core to 2 and they now run at 2.1 and 1.6 seconds respectively.  And yes they completely blew 1 day out of the water on speed so I was testing it on the largest date range I use.